# Multiple Subscription to single network request Retrofit and RXJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am new to RxJava and Retrofit. Lets say I have Retrofit service which return Observable as

```
Observable <User> login(String userName, String password);
```

How can I subscribe to this Observable in multiple places.I want to subscribe it on multiple android activities.

For eg: Lets say I have a Landing page and Login Page Activity. Login page appears after Landing Page. When I make a network request on Login Page the result should be observed on both Login Page as well as Landing Page.

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do `login(username,pw).cache()` - `cache()` autoconnects to source observable and replays all emitted items to its subscribers. It works well for observables emitting single result, as retrofit does. The other option - `replay()`, whih returns `ConnectableObservable`, and subscribes to source only when `ConnectableObservable.connect()` is called. It has many useful overloads (`replay(bufferSize)`, `replay(time, TimeUnit)`, etc), which allow one to control how many items are cached.

Comment: This is the correct response. However I'd urge @Sushant to re-thing the Observables-as-notifications model he has in mind, because it cannot work well due to inherent limitations of Observables (f.e. how can the use case "logon - logoff - logon with different credentials" work in his design?). Instead I'd suggest using an event bus.